# JS - Get global/outter variable instead of scope one

Tags: javascript

Lets assume this code:

```
const a=1,
func=_=>{
    const a=2;
    console.log(global.a,a); //Desired Output: 1 2
};
func();
```

It's important to me to use the same variable name..
I wonder if it's possible like in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's important to me to use the same variable name

You can't.

Eslint has [a rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow) you can turn on to stop you shadowing variables like this.

Comment: I had a feeling it won't be possible since I didn't find any information about this option.
In PHP I could have pointed the engine to look first on the global and then to go higher up to the `func` scope..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create another scope  `{..}` to capture the a,

```js
const a=1,
func=_=>{
  const global = {a};
  { //another scope.
    const a=2;
    console.log(global.a,a); 
  }
};
func();
```

Comment: Objects are not scopes.

Comment: @Quentin  never said they was.

Comment: Your example code differentiates between the two values by accessing one through a variable and the other as a property of an object. The use of a block inside the arrow function does create another scope, but in an entirely pointless way.

Comment: @Quentin  But yet does exactly what the OP requested.  I'm not judging him though..   But if that's what you like doing, that's fine.